# Let $A=\{n\in\mathbb{Z}: 2 \mid n \}$ and $B=\{n\in\mathbb{Z}:4\mid 2\}$.

Tags: proof-writing, solution-verification

Let $A=\{n\in\mathbb{Z}: 2 \mid n \}$ and $B=\{n\in\mathbb{Z}:4\mid 2\}$. Let $n\in\mathbb{Z}.$ Prove that $n\in\ A-B$ if an only if $n=2k$ for some odd integer $k$.

My proof: Assume $n\in A-B$. This means $n\in A$ and $n\notin B$. Since $n\in A$, then $2\mid n$. Therefore $n=2k^-$ for some odd integer $k$.

Conversely assume $n=2k$ for some odd integer $k$. This means $k=2r+1$ for some integer $r$. We can note that $n=2(2r+1)$. Since $2r+1 \in \mathbb{Z}$ then $2\mid n$ and this means $n\in A$ and $n\notin B$. So $n\in A-B$.

Is this proof correct?

Comment: I think you meant $4|n$ where you typed $4|2$ in the title and question

Comment: In the first part of your proof, you need to use $n\notin B$ to get that $n=2k$ where $k$ is odd. Otherwise $k$ could still be even from $2\mid n$.